# Riemann formula to a floor function

Tags: integration

We came across this question today at class (due the lack of time, no explanation was given)

$$ \int_{0}^{6}  \left\lfloor\frac x3\right\rfloor dx  = 3$$

Without the formula is pretty easy to see it is equal to $3$
I'd love to see how do you use the Riemann Formula in here with this floor function

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing in the two constant intervals,

$$I=3\cdot0+3\cdot1.$$

This *is* the Riemann's formula.